# Android Download Manager downloads corrupted file / cannot open file after downloading / retrofit authentication token used in download mana

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-download-manager, laravel-authorization

I'm trying to download a file from the server and after it finished downloading, the downloaded file is not recognized by the phone. I did set the mime type from the file extension of the downloaded file  and the server uses a bearer token which is why I passed the token as a header but the file is still corrupted. By the way, I use retrofit to fetch the bearer token after login. The api was created using laravel. My hypothesis is that download manager is not permitted to download the file since it is not authenticated and the token that I fetched only applies to the retrofit requests of the app. Sorry for my bad english, anyway here's my download request.

```
val downloadBaseUrl = "https://ticaphub.com/event-files/"
val urlRequest = downloadBaseUrl + filepath
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlRequest))
val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val title = URLUtil.guessFileName(urlRequest, null, null)
val cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(urlRequest)

    request.setTitle(title)
    request.setDescription("Downloading File Attachments.")
    request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Token " + this@TaskDetailsActivity
        .getSharedPreferences("loginCredential", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getString("userToken", "0"))
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookie)
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, clickedItem.name)
    request.setMimeType(getMimeFromFileName(urlRequest))
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

//The function I use to get the MIME type of the file

```
    private fun getMimeFromFileName(url: String): String {
    return URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url)
}
```

Comment: In which sense is the downloaded file corrupted? Start with the file size in bytes. Is it the same?

Comment: The downloadmanager does not need a mimetype. Every file can be handled the same as it is just a stream of bytes.

Comment: `the downloaded file is not recognized by the phone. ` I have no idea what you mean by that. If you download a file then all the bytes of the file should be equal to original. All starts with equal file sizes. After a download you can try to do something with the file. But that is another story and has nothing to do with downloading. I dont know where you have a problem. Vague language.

Comment: Have you ever got around with this issue?